# Как подключить файл из github в проект?

Tags: vue.js, github

Есть некий однофайловый компонент, который разрабатывается отдельно и залит на github.
И есть другие разработки, появляются новые...
Как можно использовать этот однофайловый компонент в новых разработках?
Просто указать путь до файла на гите, как я понимаю, не вариант.

Для конкретики.
Однофайловый компонент - это файл v-comp.vue, который внедряется на страницы существующего сайта тегом `<v-comp></v-comp>` и обрабатывается через http-vue-loader. И для разработки было бы удобно как-то подключать этот файл к проекту из гита, а не скачивать его постоянно, так как компонент постоянно дорабатывается, меняется.

Comment: использовать менеджер пакетов npm или yarn. он ставит пакет, а в lock-файле, прописывается версия, чтобы пакет не обновлялся просто так, иначе все сломается. но обновить версию можно - опять через менеджер пакетов. если гитхаб-репа не заточена под "пакетирование" - доработайте, потом отправьте МР мейнтейнеру и все будет как задумано. если мейтейнер откажется принять доработку - форкните. Погуглите Install npm From Github

Comment: Нашел вариант вставки прямой ссылки через https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ <github-name>/<repository-name>/<filename>.
Пока работает нормально, посмотрю в процессе какие возникнут проблемы с таким подключением.